# identify similar location string

Tags: java, elasticsearch, pattern-matching, geocoding, facet

Given two strings representing locations, how can we identify if both are same or different locations.For eg. "Bangalore, Karnataka" and "Bangalore, India" are both same 
location which is Bangalore. 
I have a web-based application with a text-box for "location" and user can specify values as mentioned in the above example. Input values are stored into elasticsearch and later I need to find distinct locations. For that I am using Term Facet in elasticsearch but I getting two entries,"Bangalore, Karnataka" and "Bangalore, India". Somehow I need to identify that both are same locations.
I am looking forward for java based solution for this.

Comment: what about `Bangalore, Spain` ?

Comment: Conceptually , what are you looking for is a City,State,Country Mapping kind of stuff. without that it won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a geo-coding Java API such [GeoGoogle](http://geo-google.sourceforge.net). It is open source. With that, you can call:

```
GeoUtils.distanceBetweenInKm(firstAddress.getCoordinate(), secondAddress.getCoordinate());
```